Establishing the relationship among different double integrals.
Consider
$f : [0, 1] \to [0, \infty)$ and
$h : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$,
i.e., $h$ can be both positive and negative.
Define $A = [0,1] \times [0,1]$.
Consider the following integrals:
\begin{align*}
I_{1}
& = 
\int_{A}
f(x) f(y) \, 
k(x,y) \, 
dx dy, \\
I_{2}
& =
\int_{A} 
f(x) f(y) h(y)  
k(x,y) dx dy, \\
I_{3} 
& =
\int_{A} 
f(x) f(y) h(x) h(y)
k(x,y) dx dy,
\end{align*}
where $k : A \to \mathbb{R}$ is
a positive semidefinite function
with $k \ge 0$.
Then how can we prove that
$$
I_{2}^{2}
\le 
I_{1} I_{3}?
$$
That is, consider
$$
g_{1}(x,y) 
= 
\sqrt{f(x) f(y) k(x,y)}
\quad 
\mbox{and}
\quad 
g_{2}(x,y) 
= 
\sqrt{f(x) f(y) k(x,y)}h(y).
$$
Then from Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality,
we have
\begin{align*}
\left( 
\int_{A} g_{1}(x,y) g_{2} (x,y) dx dy 
\right)^{2}
& \le 
\left( 
\int_{A} g_{1}^{2}(x,y) dxdy 
\right) 
\left( 
\int_{A} g_{2}^{2} (x,y) dx dy 
\right) \\
\mbox{i.e., }
I_{2}^{2}
& \le 
I_{1} 
\left( 
\underbrace{
\int_{A} f(x) f(y) k(x,y) h^{2}(y) dxdy
}_{=:B}  
\right) . 
\end{align*}
Now, I do not see how $B = I_{3}$,
or $B \le I_{3}$.

Are you sure you didn't mean $I_2^2 \leq I_1 I_3$? If we take $f = k = 1$ and $h = \frac12$, then $I_2^2 = I_1 I_3 = \frac14$.

@JohnBarber - Yes, it should be less or equal and is now edited. Thanks for catching that.

Do we know anything else about these functions? For instance, do we have $k(x,y) = k(y,x)$?

Yes, it is true that $k(x,y) = k(y,x)$, included in the main question. Thanks!

@JohnBarber: That's a great example, thank you! But $k(x,y) = 1 - xy$ is not a positive semi-definite function. So, I believe this example may not count as a counter example. For example, what would be the situation if we take $k(x,y) = \min{x, y} - xy$?

Is the definition of a positive semi-definite function not just a function which is non-negative in the domain of interest? If not, I withdraw the counterexample.

A function $ k : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $is called positive semi-definite if it defines a positive semi-definite kernel. This means that for any finite set of points $ x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \in \mathbb{R} $, the $ n \times n $ matrix $ K $ defined by
$$
K_{ij} = k(x_i, x_j)
$$
(where $K_{ij} $ is the element in the $ i $-th row and $ j $-th column of the matrix) must satisfy:
$$
\mathbf{z}^T K \mathbf{z} \geq 0 \quad \text{for all } \mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^n,
$$
where $\mathbf{z} $ is any vector in $ \mathbb{R}^n$.

For Riemann integrable functions $a, b: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, denote $\langle a,b \rangle=\int_A {a(x)b(y)k(x,y)dxdy}$. By the property of positive semidefinite function and the definition of Riemann integral, we have $\langle a,a \rangle \ge 0$ for all $a$. (EDIT: that is $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is actually only an semi-inner product)
Now observe that $I_1 = \langle f,f \rangle, I_2 = \langle f,fh \rangle, I_3 = \langle fh,fh \rangle$. The inequality $I_2^2\le I_1 I_3$ directly follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Thanks for this solution! The second part makes perfect sense. Would it be possible that you could provide a possible reference(s) for the first claim? That is, how is the inner product defined is actually an inner product?
We could find some function such that $a \ne 0$ but <a,a> =0.

@Matt Thanks for pointing out my mistake. We could only prove that it is a semi-inner product but that is all we need. The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality still holds in a semi-inner product space (the proof is exactly the same as the one in inner product space, by considering $\lVert x-\lambda y \rVert^2$)

Thanks for the clarification. I am still not totally sure how we can prove that $<a,b>$ is actually a semi-inner product giving $<a,a> \ge 0$ for all $a: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$?

@Matt Just verify it satisfy the definition (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Semi-Inner_Product).
